# Resaltando código con prism.js no funciona con componente

Tags: javascript

Estoy usando la libreria `prims js` (CDN) ,coloco los scripts como indica la documentacion , si tengo el componente estatico cuando carga la pagina se renderiza resaltado como quiero , ahora cuando cargo el mismo componente no se renderiza , este es el componente

```
 export const card = (value,id)=>{
    return `<div data-id=${id} class="cardcontainer">
    <i class="deleted fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
    <pre>
    <code class="language-javascript">   
    //value lo saco de el texto cargado en un text area  
    ${value}
    </code>
    </pre>
    </div>
    
    `
}
```

ahora si al cargar la pagina ya tengo el componente en el html  asi :

```
<div class="gridcards">        
        <div data-id=4 class="cardcontainer">
            <i class="deleted fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
            <pre>
            <code class=language-javascript>    
           let numero = 10 
            </code>
            </pre>
            </div>
     </div>
```

se renderiza ok (imagen de la izquierda) , pero no es lo que busco , alguna ayuda?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Y en qué lugar de tu código estás llamando al método para que Prism.js renderice el texto? Probaste con algo de esto: https://prismjs.com/docs/Prism.html#.highlightAllUnder ?

Comment: le pongo el class=language-javascript , pense que con eso solo bastaba , ahoa veo el link

Comment: La verdad nunca usé Prism.js, pero por lo general todos estos funcionan más o menos igual: cuando se cargan, intentan colorear lo que ya esté en el HTML, pero como estás cargando el `<pre>` dinámicamente, no existe contenido en el momento en que se carga Prism,js, sino que se generá después de que se carga la página, por lo que tenés que generar un hook, o disparar un método para que lo haga en el momento que quieras